# Angular - Swiper containing dynamic content

Tags: angular, dynamic, swiper.js

Hello All the Experts,

I am new to angular.
I have created 3 components.

1. Swiper
2. YouTube frame
3. Map display

Now I have to use the `swiper` component on home page two time. In first `swiper`, Need to show array of maps. And in second `swiper` I want to show array of `youtube` frames.

How can I use the same swiper (reusable) for different types of contents inside without repeating the swiper code/config?

My swiper HTML is

```
<swiper #swiper [config]="swiperConfig">
  <!-- some HTML content containing map/ youtube iFrame or anything else -->
  <ng-template swiperSlide *ngFor="let a of swiperData; let i=index">
    
  </ng-template>
</swiper>
```

Thanks in advance.

I am trying to search for the solution but couldn't get any idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like all you need to do is to create an Angular component as a wrapper to your Swiper, that component can then accept an array of items that the swiper can display.
Use that new component anywhere within your app and it will have the same swiper config.

Comment: it will help if you add some sample code